# Inequality of three prime factors of $x^2-1$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is about my experimental math observation on prime factorization of $x^2-1$

We can see, for many $x\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, the expression $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ gives result as a product of twin prime. Motivation is to understand the some patterns in twin prime through $x^2-1$.

Here, we present observations on three prime factors of $x^2-1$

Let $\mathcal{C}_p$ is a collection of three prime factor of $x^2-1$ as
$$\mathcal{C}_p=\{(p,p_1,p_2)\quad |\quad x^2-1=p\cdot p_1\cdot p_2\quad \text{and}\quad p\le p_1 \le p_2 \} $$

and $\mathcal{C}_p(i)$ is $i$th term in $\mathcal{C}_p$

Example: Table for $p=3$

| i | $\mathcal{C}_3(i)$ | $(3,\quad p_{1,i},\quad p_{2,i})$ | $p_{2,i}-p_{1,i}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63 | (3,3,7) | 4 |
| 2 | 99 | (3,3,11) | 8 |
| 3 | 195 | (3,5,13) | 8 |
| 4 | 255 | (3,5,17) | 12 |
| $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ | $\vdots$ |

consider $\Delta \mathcal{C}_{p}(i) = p_{2,i}-p_{1,i}$

> For every $i\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and for every odd prime $p$, then $\Delta \mathcal{C}_{p}(i+1)\ge \Delta \mathcal{C}_{p}(i)$

The question is whether the above claim is valid.

for $p = 2$, there is only one solution that is $ \mathcal{C}_{2}=\{ (2,2,2)\}$

this claim is verified using the following Python code

```
def pf(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors

L = []

f = lambda x: x**2-1

for i in range(2,100000):
    if pf(f(i))[0] == 3 and len(pf(f(i)))==3: 
        L.append(pf(f(i))[2]-pf(f(i))[1])
        
for i in range(len(L)-1):
    if L[i]>=L[i+1]:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

True, and for very elementary reasons. First, $p\mid x^2-1 \Leftrightarrow x\equiv \pm 1$ mod $p$. You furthermore want $\frac{x^2-1}{p} = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{p}$ to be a product of two primes $\ge p$, which amounts to saying that either

1. $x=mp-1$, and both $m$ and $mp-2$ are prime (and $\ge p$), or
2. $x=mp+1$, and both $m$ and $mp+2$ are prime (and $\ge p$).

In particular, in both cases $m\ge 3$ is odd.
The sequence of relevant $x$-values for $C_p(i)$ (for fixed prime $p$) is then a subsequence of $\{3p-1, 3p+1, 5p-1, 5p+1,\dots\}$. But the relevant $\Delta$-values are $m(p-1)-2$ in case 1) and $m(p-1)+2$ in case 2), and since $m(p-1)-2 < m(p-1)+2 \le (m+2)(p-1)-2$, the sequence of $\Delta$-values is non-decreasing (even strictly as soon as $p\ge 5$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we may extend this idea for any polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as there exist set of $N\in \mathbb{N}$ (for fix $N$), such that $\Delta\mathcal{C}_N(i)$ for $P(i)=N\cdot p_{1,i}\cdot p_{2,i}$ and holds non- decreasing criteria. is it fruitful to go through such kind of experimental stuff to construct some good theory? Regards.